# Scalar product between an eigenvector and an arbitrary vector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computational-mathematics

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix such that $Au=\lambda u$. Given that $\lambda$ is known, is there a way to compute or approximate $x'u$ for an arbitrary vector $x$ without explicitly calculating $u$?

Comment: Very related: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/08/13/eigenvectors-from-eigenvalues/